# Can't get data from Marvel API - The passed referrer not allowed for the passed API key

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to get data from the Marvel API, using this request URL:

https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=4dab7cb0585a4ea6c5d6a183f6769968

But, when using the fetch API method and logging the data to console. I'm get this:

```json
{code: "InvalidCredentials", message: "The passed referrer is not allowed for the passed API key."}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the link you shared I get this error:

`{"code":"MissingParameter","message":"You must provide a hash."}`

Accoring to the documentation, you need to provide a timestamp, `ts` and a `hash` value in the request parameter.

Also check your `Your authorized referrers` section.If you add `*` and update it will allow from any host.

See docs:
https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization

Answer (score 0):

```
Same problem was with me... follow it 100% success

//first add the following code inside head of html .

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>




//second obtain public key and private key (its easy from marvell website:-

    https://developer.marvel.com/signup)



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HONyu.png




// third:- test it with the following javascript code

        
    let para = document.getElementsByClassName('para');
    para[0].innerText="comics"

    async function apiCheck(){
    let ts = await Number(new Date());        //time stamp
    let key ="";    // fill yourself(public key)
    let pass="";    // fill yourself(private key)

    let hash= CryptoJS.MD5(ts+pass+key);  //remember use private first then public
    console.log(hash);

    let url = `http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=${ts}&apikey=${key}&hash=${hash}`;

    let response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log("response error");
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        
    }
    const jsonData = await response.json();

    para[0].innerText= JSON.stringify(jsonData.data.results[0], null, 2);

    return jsonData.data;
     
     }

    let outsy= apiCheck();
```